# Galera Donor and switching to another host for insert statement

Tags: galera

We have an application that is connecting to a Galera Cluster we are using a  connection string with multiple hosts. I.E. with MariaDB Connector J. If the first host in the connection string becomes a donor and we issue an insert statement the insert will hang until the donor stops being a donor and resumes as a regular node. We are using MariaDB Connector J is there any way to automatically switch to another host when the initial Host becomes a Donor? We tried using the keyword sequential, but it did not work in this case. Is there a setting in Galera that will allow a donor to immediatly execute an insert statement and return? How is this normally handled? Resynch can take up to 20 minutes and our program cannot pause that long.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured it out. I changed the setting wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries to on. With the keyword sequential, this allowed the driver to skip the donor and move to the next up host. If anyone has any alternative solution please post it. I thought I should post my solution so it would help others facing a similar challenge.